# Table display block behavior

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a table with `display: block; max-width: 100px; overflow-x: auto` css properties.

In some cases everything is fine, but in this snippet http://jsfiddle.net/TLP8x/ you can see that `thead` and `tbody` does not take all possible width.

Is this possible to make them take all possible width, just as usual table behavior?

I tried to use `display: table-row` and other display values on `tbody`, `thead` and `tr`, but this did not help me.

Comment: Do you have a reason to use `display:block` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `display: block` attribute of the `<table>` and to apply `width: 100%`

http://jsfiddle.net/TLP8x/4/

Comment: Thank you, Balthazar. I know that display block is wrong for tables but my problem is that in other cases I need to add it, so my question is how to manage `tbody` width 100% with `display: block` on `table`.

Comment: Maybe the problem can be passed if you include the `table` into a `div` ? http://jsfiddle.net/TLP8x/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the behaviour you desire by:

- Removing the 'display:block' as noted above.
- Updating the table declaration to: table class="blocked_table" style="width:100%"

With those done, the table cells consume the entire 100px box in a 50/50 split.